# Why the value of trackbar of SADWinowSize_slider become 0 when it assign to sbm->state.SADWindowSize, in my code

Tags: c++, opencv

I am testing stereoBM tuning parameters by GUI using opencv.

Below is my code.

```
Mat out1, out2;

Size imageSize = out1.size();

StereoBM sbm;

/// Initialize values
int preFilterType_slider = 0, preFilterCap_slider = 0, preFilterSize_slider = 0,

minDisparity_slider = 0, uniqnessRatio_slider = 0, textureThreshold_slider = 0,

speckleRange_slider = 0, sADWindowSize_slider = 5, spackleWindowSize_slider = 0,

numDisparities_slider = 0, numDisparities2_slider = 0;



int preFilterType_max = 1, preFilterCap_max = 61, preFilterSize_max = 100,

minDisparity_max = 200, uniqnessRatio_max = 2500, textureThreshold_max = 10000,

speckleRange_max = 500, sADWindowSize_max = 255, spackleWindowSize_max = 200,

numDisparities_max = 500, numDisparities2_max = 0;


Mat dispt, disp8, g1, g2;

void on_trackbar_bmTunning(int , void*)
{

    if (preFilterSize_slider % 2 == 0) preFilterSize_slider++;  //odd
    if (preFilterSize_slider < 5) preFilterSize_slider = 5;     //started from 5
    if (preFilterSize_slider > 255) preFilterSize_slider = 255; // to 255

    if (preFilterCap_slider < 1) preFilterCap_slider = 1;
    if (preFilterCap_slider > 63) preFilterCap_slider = 63;

    if (sADWindowSize_slider % 2 == 0) sADWindowSize_slider++;
    if (sADWindowSize_slider <= 5) sADWindowSize_slider = 5;
    if (sADWindowSize_slider > 255)sADWindowSize_slider = 255;
    if (sADWindowSize_slider >= MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height))
        sADWindowSize_slider = MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

    if (minDisparity_slider < 0) minDisparity_slider = 0;

    if (numDisparities_slider <1) numDisparities_slider = 1;

    if (textureThreshold_slider < 0) textureThreshold_slider = 1;

    if (uniqnessRatio_slider < 0) uniqnessRatio_slider = 1;


    //disp8 = g1.clone();

    sbm.state->speckleWindowSize = spackleWindowSize_slider;
    sbm.state->speckleRange = speckleRange_slider;
    sbm.state->preFilterSize = preFilterSize_slider; // 41
    sbm.state->preFilterCap = preFilterCap_slider; //31
    sbm.state->SADWindowSize = sADWindowSize_slider; //41
    sbm.state->minDisparity = minDisparity_slider *-16;//-64
    sbm.state->numberOfDisparities = numDisparities_slider * 16; //128
    sbm.state->textureThreshold = textureThreshold_slider; //10
    sbm.state->uniquenessRatio = uniqnessRatio_slider; //15

    sbm(g1, g2, dispt);

    normalize(dispt, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);

    imshow("Tune BM Window ", disp8);
}

int test2_bmTunning() {

    out1 = imread("aloeL.jpg");

    out2 = imread("aloeR.jpg");

    cvtColor(out1, g1, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cvtColor(out2, g2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    namedWindow("Tune BM Window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    createTrackbar("Number of Disparities", "Tune BM Window", &preFilterType_slider, preFilterType_max, 0);

    createTrackbar("Pre Filter Cap", "Tune BM Window", &preFilterCap_slider, preFilterCap_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Pre Filter Size", "Tune BM Window", &preFilterSize_slider, preFilterSize_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Minimum Disparity", "Tune BM Window", &minDisparity_slider, minDisparity_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Uniqueness Ratio", "Tune BM Window", &uniqnessRatio_slider, uniqnessRatio_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Texture Threshold", "Tune BM Window", &textureThreshold_slider, textureThreshold_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Speckle Range", "Tune BM Window", &speckleRange_slider, speckleRange_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Block Size", "Tune BM Window", &sADWindowSize_slider, sADWindowSize_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Speckle Window Size", "Tune BM Window", &spackleWindowSize_slider, spackleWindowSize_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    createTrackbar("Number of Disparity", "Tune BM Window", &numDisparities_slider, numDisparities_max, on_trackbar_bmTunning);

    /// Show some stuff
    //on_trackbar_bmTunning(sADWindowSize_slider, 0);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem :**

The problem occurs when the value of SADWindowSlize value from trackbar slider is assigned to sbm.state->SADWindowSize = sADWindowSize_slider; //41

In this line of code, the value of sADWindowSize_slider becomes 0 and so it throws a run time error that SAD window size should be odd and in between 5 to 255.

I am not able to understand how the value of SADWindowSize_slider becomes 0..

Please guide me in finding the reason for this and help me in solving the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We found problem in our code.**

**SADWindowSize should be odd and in between 5 ~ 255. 
Therefore, this condition is not needed and also not make sense.**

```
if (sADWindowSize_slider >= MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height))
        sADWindowSize_slider = MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
```

Just delete above mentioned line of code, run and tune parameters for your iamge and enjoy result.

Have Fun!!